# REST representation for xml

Tags: xml, json, api, rest, wadl

I'm building a REST api and debating what format should I use for the xml representation.
I know it can be one defined in house but there are also lots for formats.
wadl looks interesting but there seems to be a debate about it and it's new as well.

what are the recommendations(best practices for it)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as it's valid XML that's a start.  My general strategy for simple REST/XML services is as follows:

For parsing, you almost certainly want a single, always present root node, e.g. "response", which can contain either a result element or an error element.
E.g.:

```
<response>
  <result>
    <answer>5</answer>
  </result>
</response>
```

The way you structure the results is up to you.  You can decide whether to hold data in elemenets as CDATA (text notes, as show above) or as required attributes, e.g.

```
<answer value="5"/>
```

Another thing that is sometimes useful is to include your original query in the response, e.g.:

```
<response query="operation=add&a=2&b=3"> .. </response>
```

That way if you have multiple queries outstanding you can match them back to the original request.

Comment: my question is more related with - should I invent my own way to do representation as you describe, risking perhaps to omit some of the REST benefits or just use a well known representation.

Comment: Well the WADL description is a way to formally describe your REST service - but the XML response format is still something you define and then describe in the WADL response representation.  Unless your service is trivial, e.g. literally posting text to or reading text from a name resource, you will usually need to create a format for your data.

Comment: ok - so basically i do my plan on resources etc and how to represent them into xml - then i can use wadl to actually describe parameters type per method etc.  - are there any constraints to this ?

Comment: Constraints?  Not apart from writing it so that it's valid and correct.  It's a REST interface - you choose how to represent your resources (URLs), what the operations mean (the HTTP methods) and return whatever you want to the client that lets you do what you need to do.  If you wanted very strict discipline and lots of things that you /have/ to do, you would use SOAP :)